# Any KNX-speaking simple Decora rocker switches?

Tags: home-automation, knx

I'm rebuilding my house later this year. I plan to do all the lighting using KNX controls, so every light will be an actuator.

For wall switches, I'm looking to find something much simpler and more familiar than touchscreens or capacitive switches. I'm looking for a Decora-style rocker switch that will send KNX signals over twisted pair wiring. Properties I'm looking for:

- Decora style look
- Momentary action "on" and "off" buttons (depress the top or bottom of the paddle momentarily)
- Signals via KNX over twisted pair wiring
- Powered via twisted pair wiring (I don't care if it's the same wires as the signaling)

Has anyone ever seen such a product?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions related to software development. Maybe you want https://diy.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Decora style", but there are so many KNX push-button designs out there that you sure will find some. But your question is indeed off-topic here so it will probably be closed soon.

Comment: If you find a conventional push button/rocker in the desired design you can connect it to a KNX push button interface (like [this one](https://www.mdt.de/EN_Universal_Interface.html) or similar from most KNX manufacturers).